# Aligning label and input by 3:1

Tags: reactjs, css, flexbox, react-native-flexbox

I have inputs and labels in inside info class and I want each label and input to align by 1:3 on a single row no matter what the screen size is, plus I won't mind using flex classes, I just want a solution. Cheers

**css**

```
.info {
    border: 2px solid steelblue;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.info input[type = 'text']{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid orange;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

**JSX**

```
<div className = 'form'>

    <h3 id = 'intro'>Join Us Here</h3><hr/>

    <div className = 'info'>
        <div>
            <label>Business Name:</label> <input type='text' placeholder='Business Name' />        
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Owner Name:</label> <input type='text' placeholder='Owner Name' />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Receptionist Name:</label> <input type='text' placeholder='Receptionist Name' />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

[image: i Want it like this but in 1 ratio 3]

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it...SO has rules about that....and it will be detected

Comment: it was a fair question and i have done research. you don't know from there what i have done here

Comment: Hi @SyedBaryalay , did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I agree on comments that you should do at least some research and this is simplest flex layout ever it's simple as adding `display:flex` on parent div and adding `flex: 1` and `flex: 3` on components.

I am sending you a working solution on codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/wo6z1j23ll